# C# string parse to array

Tags: c#, string, parsing

i need to parse for example such string:
*"Hello, my name is Boris, [image1.jpg]  i like drinking tea [img2.jpg]"*

and i want to get array of strings:

```
Arr[0] ="Hello, my name is Boris, "
Arr[1] ="image1.jpg"
Arr[2] ="  i like drinking tea "
Arr[3] ="img2.jpg"
```

Comment: Will the square brackets be always there?

Comment: Well how is it supposed to be split up? Do you have a common-seperator (like a comma?)

Comment: Not a downvoter, but it seems like a person visited this link just to down vote all posts :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do the trick if there will always be square brackets in your string.

```
string str = "Hello, my name is Boris, [image1.jpg] i like drinking tea [img2.jpg]";
string[] Arr = str.Split(new char[] { '[', ']' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Replace` to make all the "[" be "]" and then `Split` with them, like this:

```
str = str.Replace("[", "]");

string[] Arr = str.Split(']');
```

Comment: @downvoter, please leave a message so i'll know what's wrong

Comment: Not my downvote but this is not going to work

Comment: @SriramSakthivel why?

Comment: This will compile when `']'`. Indeed it works otherwise +1

Comment: It should be `string[] strs = str.Split(']');` Good solution.

Comment: seriously i just got two downvotes and no comment. what is wrong?

Comment: I'm sure you already know why this is not the best solution. `str.Split(new char[] { '[', ']' }` does the same without needing to replace.

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions:

```
    var regex = new Regex(@"(.+)\[(.+)\](.+)\[(.+)\]");
    Match match = regex.Match("");
    if (match.Success) {
        match = match.NextMatch();
        string[] parts = match.Groups.Cast<Group>().Where(x => x.Success).Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
string[] strs = Regex.Split(str, "(?<Token>\[.*?\])", RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

Comment: The pattern should be a verbatin string literal (`@`). Also, this will result in an array of 5 elements instead of 4.